# HTML case sensitive issue

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Case Sensitive Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087775/html-case-sensitive-issues)

I have this:

```
<div class="menuHolder">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="with_ul"><a id="panorama"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">panorama</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu_1">
          <li><a href="abc.html">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!/pageMore">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!/pageMore">History</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have a file called aBc.html already

When I clicked on Test, I get a 404. If I change the line to

```
<li><a href="aBc.html">Test</a></li>
```

it works fine.

I know that HTML is not case sensitive, but then why is this happening? Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A URL is case-sensitive past the domain name. `example.com` and `EXAMPLE.COM` both resolve to the same address, but anything after the domain name is case-sensitive.

Now come the filesystems. Windows uses NTFS, which is not case-sensitive, so `abc.html` and `aBc.html` refer to the same file. Most Linux distros use EXT4, which is case-sensitive, so `abc.html` and `aBc.html` are two different files.

In short, your webserver is running on a filesystem where filenames are case-sensitive, so `abc.html` and `aBc.html` refer to two different files.

Comment: This is only true for web servers running on UNIX-like OSes, it doesn't apply to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX-like platforms, filenames **are** case sensitive, only Windows doesn't care about case. This has actually nothing to do with HTML being case insensitive.

However take note that with IIS on Windows, virtual paths **are** case sensitive, but not actual files paths.

So under Windows it is correct to assume that `aBc.html` and `abc.html` are exactly the same file.

Because of this, for compatibility reasons, one should **always match the case** of the paths in HTML with the paths on the file system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are case-sensitive on Windows as well. From what I remember, only FAT doesn't preserve filenames case.

Comment: I'm 100% positive that Windows is case insensitive.

Comment: I guess you're right! I never knew that.

Answer (score 1):

Some constructs in HTML are case-sensitive, some are not, partly depending on HTML version. The `href` attribute value is always case-sensitive, as far as HTML is considered.

The value of an `href` attribute value is processed as a URL (or, formally, URI), and URLs are case-sensitive except for parts specified to be case-insensitive. Here the value gets resolved into an absolute URL so that the string `abc.html` becomes the path part, and that part is *not* exempted from case-sensitivity.

What the *server* does with the URL is then at its discretion. It may well treat `abc.html` and `aBc.html` (or `abc.html` and `foobar`, for that matter) identically, as referring to the same resource.

Contrary to popular belief, URLs are not filenames, and servers can play many things with them instead of simply mapping them to filenames. It is fairly common to make path parts case-insensitive, using certain rewriting rules in the server.

But if the server is running, for example, an out-of-the-box version of Apache with default settings on Linux, which is a rather common setup, then path parts are mapped to filenames in a simple manner, and in the Linux filesystem those names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

So, basic answer: if you're hosted on a UNIX based platform, it matters. Word of advice: name EVERYTHING in lower case letters, it will make your life so much easier